# How to show $\displaystyle s=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{A_i}$ measurable implies $A_i$ measurable for all $i=1, \ldots, n$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a measurable set and $s:X\longrightarrow [0, \infty)$ be a simple function. It is easy to see $$s=\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \chi_{A_i},$$ where $\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\}$ is the set of distinct values of $s$ and $A_i=\{x\in X; s(x)=\alpha_i\}$.

Let us suppose $s$ is measurable. How to show each $A_i$ is also measurable?

I think I should see each $A_i$ as the inverse image of some open set in $[0, \infty)$, however, $$A_i=s^{-1}(\alpha_i),$$ and $\{\alpha_i\}$ is not open in $[0, \infty)$ so I don't know what to do. Any hint?

Comment: Can you find an open interval containing $\alpha_i$ but no $\alpha_j$, $j\ne i$?

Comment: Cool man =) It suffices taking the open interval $(\alpha_i-\varepsilon, \alpha_i+\varepsilon)$ where $\varepsilon=\min\{|\alpha_i-\alpha_j|: i\neq j\}$, right?

Answer (score 1):

Another (only slightly different) way is to begin with a general lemma:

**Lemma** *If $f$ is measurable, then each level set $f^{-1}(b)$ is measurable.*

*Proof*: $f^{-1}(b) = \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty f^{-1}((b-1/n,b+1/n))$. $\quad \Box$

Then apply the lemma to $s^{-1}(\alpha_i)$.